# How do I present a word ending in “‑f ” that may be plural or singular?

Tags: grammatical-number, orthography, parentheses, parenthetical-plural

When we don’t know if a word refers to one or more, it is common to use a parenthetical *s*:

- door/doors: door(s)
- lamp/lamps: lamp(s)

What’s the best or *least awkward* way to render this for words that change their form when pluralizing, such as words ending in *-f* ?

- shelf/shelves: shelf(ves)?
- dwarf/dwarves: dwarf(ves)?

Comment: ...I won't swear to it, but I'm pretty sure I've seen just (s) used with words even if that's not how you'd form the plural, it just denotes "possibly plural."

Comment: Most of them take both *-s* and *-ves*. *Leaf* is the only one I can think of that is strictly pluralized as *leaves*.

Comment: @Jimi Oke: Really? *Shelfs, dwarfs, wolfs, halfs, hoofs, thiefs, roofs.* None of those look right.

Comment: OK, that was a blanket statement. However, a quick look at the dictionary will reveal that *dwarfs/dwarves* and *hoofs/hooves* are correct. The only plural of *roof* is *roofs*. And I concede that *shelf*, *wolf*, *half* and *thief* are always pluralized with *ves*.

Comment: Dwarfs is the correct term when referring to humans with Dwarfism or star classifications. Dwarves is generally used in the fantasy fiction realm.

Comment: Related: [Parenthetical pluralization of words ending in '-y'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50885) and [so on](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parenthetical-plural).

Comment: In particular, the more general question is [How to write a parenthetical plural when the noun pluralizes irregularly?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12668)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've typically seen this done by maintaining the format and leaving the reader to make the appropriate change in pronunciation.

- self(s)
- dwarf(s)

There may be a better way, but I haven't seen it in usage and this is certainly easy to program for if that's what you happen to be doing. The change is not particularly difficult to make for a native speaking reader, and even for non-natives the other alternatives are likely to be more confusing.

Comment: The only "better" way I can think of is to rephrase, generally by presuming plurality.