# Parenthetical pluralization of words ending in '-y'

Tags: grammatical-number, orthography, writing-style, silent-letters, parenthetical-plural

Sentences constructed with a word written in the singular and parenthetically in the plural are straightforward when that word does not end in *-y*, e.g.:

> List all applicable **employee(s)**.

How does one handle words ending in *-y*? Is this correct:

> I will attend the **party(ies)**.

Comment: I wouldn't get too hung up allowing for the possibility of only one - if you need to allow for more than one anyway, just use the plural. Otherwise it'll do your head in when you consider the grammaticality of your first "instruction" if it were to only be in the singular. *"List all applicable employee"* is simply nonsense, and I don't see how adding *(s)* gets you out of that.

Comment: There are no rules for these things and I am no better placed to devise a method than you are!

Comment: It is possible that there is no convention in this case. Perhaps: Will the responsible party/parties please come forward.

Comment: @medica That is exactly how I would write it. Depending on the context, either _party/parties_ or _party (parties)_. Similarly, _man/men_ or _man (men)_.

Comment: @tchrist I would not approve of the 'accepted answer' on that post. *Party(ies)* is fine and very (much more?) common.

Comment: This comes with practice (i.e. lot of reading and listening).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Ane possible rewording of "List all applicable employee(s)." to explicitly allow possibility of a singular (or vacuously, zero) employee while retaining legitimate consistent grammaticality could be as such: "Fully list applicable employee[/s].". Other--in my opinion, less-neutral-- words can be used instead of 'fully'; such as 'exhaustively', 'sweepingly'.

Comment: @11qq00: I don't think including adverbial ***fully, briefly***, etc. to modify ***list*** makes the awkward syntax much better. What *would* make a difference is including "adjectival" ***any*** to modify the "ambiguous plural subject" here. I see no real problem with *List **any** applicable employee(s)*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  ~~Aye, if "any" there be taken to mean “*all of* any[ existent] applic..” (as opposed to "any[ arbitrary, or by some-whatever metric…] applic..").

Answer (score 16, accepted):

An alternative to the use of parentheses to provide both singular and plural forms is to separate them with a slash:

> party/parties

This would be preferred in this and other similarly awkward formations such as *wife/wives*, and in special cases such as *mouse/mice*.

Comment: If you're writing something that you may be judged on (whether for a grade, or for business in terms of your competence, or simply by other grammar Nazis that you want to impress) then I would go with this. But I think this is hardly more concise than fully writing out " or " instead of using a slash. For 99% of the writing I do, I would just go with the parenthetical (ies).

Comment: "Would be preferred" by whom, exactly? Not by me.

Comment: For short words (under three syllables / ten letters or so) like this, listing both number possibilities looks as good or better than the 'short-hand' approach, since the relative space savings for the alternative is smaller than with longer nouns.

Answer (score 7):

"Party(ies)" is certainly used in official contexts.

[https://www.google.com.au/search?q=%22party%28ies%29%22+site:.gov](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=%22party%28ies%29%22+site%3a.gov)

Answer (score 5):

I think the following may also be an acceptable way of dealing with an uncertain plural ending in "y":

> part(y/ies)

Answer (score 1):

A safe, formal alternative is of course to use the singular and the plural with `or`, e.g.

```
I will attend the party or parties.
```

Answer (score -3):

When we can't continue a word in brackets to show the options, we must show both(all) words.

Thus:

```
   I/We will attend your party
```

But:

```
  You(s) are invited to the party (ie alone or with a friend)
```

Thus in your case you need to write:

```
  Party (Parties)
```

Comment: _You(s)_? That’s eye dialect (and only works for IrE, ScE, and some dialects of AmE to boot), so hardly appropriate for any kind of even semi-formal writing.