# Parenthetical plurals of nouns with stems that are written differently in singular and plural

Tags: grammatical-number, orthography, software, silent-letters, parenthetical-plural

[Related Question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50885/parenthetical-pluralization-of-words-ending-in-y) that I don't like the answer to because it conflicts with my industry's standards (see bottom of post).

**Edit**: I asked a *new* question because I'm looking for an *answer*, not an *alternative* (the prior question will likely be forgotten because the original question wasn't addressed), even if that answer is "there is no correct way".

---

If I have a grocery list that tells me to buy meat and fruit, but I don't know whether I'm buying 1 or more types of each, I may write something along the lines of:

```
Buy:
-meat(s)
-fruit(s)
```

How do I pluralize a word in this fashion that requires a suffix change to become plural?

```
candy -> candies
```

It doesn't seem right to use any of the following:

```
candy(s)
candy(ies)
cand(y)(ies)
cand(y/ies)
```

---

Background: I write software, and this type of notation seems common, but I've never run into this type of problem: usually "(s)" after the word works without any problem.

For example: from Microsoft Word:
[image]

Comment: @FumbleFingers The OP is looking for the parenthetical approach. The answer he and you cite gives an alternative, but does not answer his question.

Comment: @bib: That's as may be, but it's still *the same question*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers What is the proper course of action here? This may be the same question, but it has been marked as "accepted" with an unacceptable answer.

Comment: Voted to re-open because the other question does not answer this specific question. BUT I don't think there is a common way that uses parentheses, and it's ridiculous to reject a common method on the basis that it doesn't meet industry standards. I would suggest "candy/ies" or just opt for one or the other.