# How do we add the plural between brackets when it's optional?

Tags: grammatical-number

When part of a word is added between brackets to indicate that it might be an option, how do we deal with the plural version in grammatical terms?

For example:

> The student(s)

Also, when the noun ends with a 'y', do we follow the "y" with (ies), too?

> Signatory(ies)

Thank you,

Comment: For the second part of the question, see [Parenthetical pluralization of words ending in '-y'](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50885) and the linked questions.