# What is the optional plural form of a word that ends in “‑y”?

Tags: grammatical-number, orthography, parentheses, silent-letters, parenthetical-plural

I guess “optional plural” is the correct term.  I’m referring to things like

- It can be found at the following **location(s)**.
- Please pick up your **ticket(s)**.

But how do I do that to a word that ends in *‑y*? Take *category* for example: “category(s)” doesn’t seem correct, because *categorys* is a misspelling.  But everything else I have tried looks ridiculous.

What’s the correct approach here?

Comment: There is no **correct usage** unless it's stipulated in a style manual. And then you must be sure that the style manual is the one you're supposed to be using. If no style manual is prescribed, then find one that you like and use that.

Comment: I can't find a reference, but I've always written "category(ies)".

Comment: Google [reveals that both are used](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%5Bcategory%28ies%29%5D%2C%5Bcategory%28s%29%5D&year_start=1960&year_end=2102&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) so this seems more of a style thing. Suggest you ask at Writers.SE?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9694/167443

Comment: This is not a question about a plural form or "optional plural" form (which doesn't exist). This is a question about abbreviation. See my answer.

Comment: Related, and at least one exact dupe: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/50885 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/12668 Less related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/49048 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/11380

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Words that end in *-**C**y* regularly go to *-ies*, while those that end in *-**V**y* regularly go to *-**V**ys* (where ***C*** means a consonant and ***V*** means a vowel).

- bunny > bunnies, telly > tellies, category > categories
- Monday > Mondays, boy > boys, monkey > monkeys

But *money > monies* is irregular.

You could write

- Please select your preferred category or categories.
- Please select your preferred category(-ies).
- Please select one or more categories.

---

### Stackoverflow Content

If you have a computer program that does the equivalent of:

```
printf("%d %s(s) selected.\n", count, thingie);
```

Then you are automatically doing it wrong.   A computer should know how to count.  And inflect. It is pure laziness — and not the good kind, either — on the part of programmer to write

> ```
> 1 file(s) deleted.
> ```

That sort of thing is extremely aggravating.  Please do not do it. In the specific case of having a category for a thingie, you would use

```
printf("%d categor%s selected.\n", count, count == 1 ? "y" : "ies");
```

Accept no substitutes.

In the more general case, you need an English noun inflector.

Comment: I'm not struggling with making the word plural, I'm struggling with how to denote that it's *optionally* plural.

Comment: @JeremyWiggins Then use (-ies).

Comment: That “Accept no substitutes” notion is wrongheaded since your code doesn't work! It produces "SyntaxError: invalid syntax".  Instead write `print "{:d} categor{:s} selected.\n".format(count, "y" if count==1 else "ies");`, which produces `1 category selected.` when count==1 or `4 categories selected.` when count==4.

Comment: Stackoverflow content (since you opened the door):  Assuming the only variation that needs to be covered is 1/(0 or many) will flunk localization.  Localization is hard; no trivial solution will work universally.  Mozilla's guidance contains 16 different sets of pluralization rules.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Localization_and_Plurals

Comment: @DanNeely I’d be happy if they just got ***English*** noun singular–plurals inflections right.  They never seem to.  Yes, simultaneously dealing with others is much harder.  I don’t much like any `printf`-based solution, even with the argument games.

Comment: @DanNeely This is ELU. I don’t think we need worry about such things.

Comment: @jwpat7 -1: He's obviously using C-like syntax, and you know what he meant: there's no excuse for not having your program automatically pluralize trivial English nouns.

Comment: That's neat if you write a program for one language. But different languages inflect different counts differently and if you happen to localize a program which is filled with such english-related hacks, you really want to strangle the author.

Comment: @SF: Well, if you're localising an application that doesn't use resource files, you really want to strangle the author. And if you are using resource files, this is a trivial problem.

Comment: @tchrist - I appreciate the content from stackoverflow and you're 100% correct as far as that goes.  However, this question was more about the language rule than a programming rule, as I couldn't find any recommendations or rules online and I was curious.

Comment: @pdr: good luck localizing resources that stand for "s" "ies" "y" "ys" "ity" "bunn" and so on. After someone implements dynamic inflection by building words from pieces in software (like tchrist suggested), the case is lost, resources won't save you. And normally preparing for localization by replacing all static strings with resource references in the source isn't a very terrible job (tedious and boring yes, but doable) as long as the author of the software didn't begin to get creative with building a grammar engine.

Comment: @SF: I am suggesting that if you're using resource files, it's as easy to have a CATEGORY and a CATEGORY_PLURAL and choose between those as it is to chose between "category" and "categories".

Comment: @pdr: I agree, and this is what will work. But if instead of CATEGORY and CATEGORY_PLURAL you have CATEGORY_CORE, CATEGORY_SUFFIX_SINGULAR and CATEGORY_SUFFIX_PLURAL, CATEGORY_SUFFIX_SINGULAR_POSSESSIVE, CATEGORY_SUFFIX_PLURAL_POSSESSIVE, you're really getting tempted to stop translating and start shopping for piano wire. Not to mention, rules differ between languages, for example in Polish, the plural suffix changes between counts ending with 1234 and 056789 (*52 kategorie*, *25 kategorii*) meaning the whole inflection-in-software effort is wasted anyway.

Comment: "That sort of thing is extremely aggravating" ... You are, I'm sorry, hopelessly incorrect.  **bloatware** is an extremely old-fashioned idea (fully 15-20 years out of date).  The **primary guiding principle** in software today is "KISS" -- leading to reliability.  I can assure you that if you worked for a software engineering concern that made, say, the software that steers airplanes, and you tried to add "happy noun forms" to the interface, either the planes would crash or you'd be sacked.

Comment: Just FTR note that (if you were working 20 yrs ago) it really doesn't work like that.  In any real-world software package or IDE it would be something to do with the overall handling of various languages available in the game, aviation software, or whatever the case is.

Comment: I have better things to do than write code for making something prettier than `file(s)` when I'm adding a print statement for debugging something and that I'm going to disable except during testing. `file(s)` has its place. I won't argue that that place is in a final presentation or something, but a valid use case DOES exist. The answer should focus more on how to handle `category(s)` vs `category(-ies)` or whatever and less on scolding.

Comment: Beyond programming, what if I want an abbreviation for "category or categories" to fit in a bullet point or some other situation where space is tight and I am also not supplying a counter because I don't know it? Perhaps you can correct `1 file(s)` into `1 file`, but you can't collapse `? file(s)` when you don't know the value of `?`.

Comment: I too really hate it when software generates text like "1 file(s)".  Even some stuff made by Micro$oft does it.  If you can't program something as simple as detecting singular versus plural, how on earth did you manage to create software products that are many orders of magnitude more complex than this?  But as Jeremy has indicated, this is outside the scope of his question.

Comment: I was just copyediting some text that was using "another study(s)" in some places and "another study/studies" in others, and thinking about how to write it better.  It took me a few moments to notice the word "another" in that position and thus that this furthermore made it not quite make sense.  In the end I realised "one or more other studies" is the best wording.

Answer (score 10):

When you write *category(s)*, or *category(ies)*, or whatever, you are not writing an “optional plural” form of the word *category*. You are writing an **abbreviation** of the noun phrase “category (or categories)”.

To see this is so, ask yourself how you would pronounce *category(s)* and convey the intended meaning? You couldn’t. You would have to say something like “category (or categories)”, and that, then, is also how you would write it out.

How you abbreviate that noun phrase is up to you (and your editor or style guide, if you have one).

And notice that this isn’t even a question about English. This question and its answer apply to any written language in which you want to abbreviate a noun phrase containing both the singular and the plural form.

Comment: If you want to pronounce "category(s)" you just use air-parentheses. Like air-quotes, only, for parens.

Comment: Pointing out that "category(s)" is an abbreviation for "category or categories" is the key.

Comment: How does the specific type of abbreviation this is not constitute an optional plural?  Does the term "optional plural" have a specific, different meaning?