# Countable noun with irregular plural form

Tags: irregular-plurals, parenthetical-plural

How can I express a countable noun together with its irregular plural form? For example, we may have the following sentence:

> Find all critical point(s) of this function.

Since we do not know if the function has one or more critical points, we use the expression "point(s)".

What if the noun has an irregular plural form?

For example, should one say

> Find all maximum/maxima of the function.

instead of using the parenthesis as we did in "point(s)"?

Comment: Writing it is not saying it. Write what you say.  There are no slashes in speech.

Comment: I would replace"all" with "the" so it makes sense for singular use.

Comment: Do not complicate. *All* **always** takes the plural, even if that has the ultimate possibility of being more than one, one, or none.

Answer (score 2):

Parenthetical plural is mainly used in statements, not when trying to determine the number of something. In the latter context we just use ordinary plural, and it's understood that the result might be just a single item.

So you would write

> Find all the critical points of this function.
>   Find all the maxima and minima of the function.

Comment: Thanks! And how to use parenthetical plural when the noun has an irregular plural form?

Comment: I think you just don't bother, it's too clumsy.

Comment: So just use the plural form?

Comment: Yes, that's what would be done.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Comment: This answer differs, though: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12668/how-to-write-a-parenthetical-plural-when-the-noun-pluralizes-irregularly

Comment: Awkward example, since a function with 5 maxima still may have only one maximum. And it might not coincide with any of them.

Comment: "Find all the **maxima** of the function." Only the *maxima*.

Comment: See also, my comment at OP.